# Different layout for tablets

Tags: android, layout, fragment, tablet

I need to implement a diffent layout for tablets.
I am aware of the different layout folders, such as w600dp or w720dp.

But I want to implement also different functions for tablets.
So my phonelayout consists of 3 Tabs, but my tabletlayout should consist of two fragments.
The first fragment is one of the tabs from the phonelayout. 
The second fragment has a TabHost with the remaining two tabs of the phonelayout.

So I have to implement different function for phone/tablet.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please read similiar question/response [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503941/activities-vs-fragments/21504010#21504010)

Comment: you could refer the android fragments example. It shows one fragment in portrait and two in landscape orientation. You could look into it.